# Reversing integer values of an array using assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am trying to reverse integer values of an array using assembly language. Please check the below program and correct me.

```
;Reverse array of 32-bit integers

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.DATA

 intarray DWORD 600h,700h,300h,400h,500h,200h,100h

 .CODE

main PROC

mov esi, offset intarray
mov ecx, lengthof intarray

lea edi,[esi+(lengthof intarray*sizeof intarray)-sizeof intarray]
L1:
mov eax,[esi]              ;eax = value at start
mov ebx,[edi]
;xchg eax,ebx   ;ebx = value at end
mov [edi],eax              ;Store value from start at end
mov [esi],ebx              ;Store value from end at start
add esi,sizeof intarray                  ;esi = address of next item at start
sub edi,sizeof intarray                  ;edi = address of next item at end
cmp esi,edi                ;Have we reached the middle?
loop L1   

call DumpRegs
call WriteInt

ret 

;call DumpMem

exit

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Format as code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The `loop` instruction does not what you expect!

> ```
> cmp esi,edi                ;Have we reached the middle?
> loop L1
> ```

When you did the compare of these pointers you got certain flags from the CPU to allow you to interpret the result of the comparison. By using the `loop` instruction you neglected this!
What you need is a conditional jump that goes to the top of the loop as long as the `ESI` pointer is smaller than the `EDI` pointer. Since addresses are unsigned we use the condition **below** here.

```
cmp  esi, edi                ;Have we reached the middle?
jb   L1
```

Comment: @BANDIHEMANTH Welcome on StackOverflow. Please consider to accept this answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it. Doing so will earn you 2 points and is the preferred way to deal with an answer that you found helpful. Saying thanks of course is always a much appreciated bonus.